# Finding correct Firebase Auth id_token on $onAuthStateChanged

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire

I am currently using `Angular 1.5.8`, `Firebase 3.3.0`, and `AngularFire 2.0.2`. When I call `$firebaseAuth.$signInWithPopup`, the promise returns with a firebase user that includes `firebase.user.idToken`, but when I call `$onAuthStateChanged`, firebase user does not return with a `.user` property. What is the correct token to use for server authentication from the $onAuthStateChanged function?

I was using the `md` property, but then it stopped working and switched to a `kd` property and I realized that not every user has that. Is it the `_lat` property? It seems to work this way, but I can't seem to find any documentation around it. Or is this not the correct way to be using the token on an Auth State Change? Is there a best practice? Here is the object I have being returned from the promise.

[image]

I appologize for the image, but what is strange is that if I JSON.stringify(firebaseUser) and print it, I end up with a completely different object where `firebaseUser.stsTokenManager.accessToken` would give me the right key, but if I try `firebaseUser.stsTokenManager.accessToken` it says that `stsTokenManager` is undefined.

```
{
  "uid": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "displayName": "Luke Schlangen",
  "photoURL": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "email": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX@XXXXX.com",
  "emailVerified": true,
  "isAnonymous": false,
  "providerData": [
    {
      "uid": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
      "displayName": "Luke Schlangen",
      "photoURL": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
      "email": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX@XXXXX.com",
      "providerId": "google.com"
    }
  ],
  "apiKey": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "appName": "[DEFAULT]",
  "authDomain": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "stsTokenManager": {
    "apiKey": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "refreshToken": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "accessToken": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "expirationTime": XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
  },
  "redirectEventId": null
}
```

All of the code seems functional now and seems to be working for every user, but I'm wondering, is there a best-practice for this? Should I be using `JSON` to convert and then selecting the property from that object? Or is `_lat` the proper way to grab this key?

```
var app = angular.module("sampleApp", ["firebase"]);
app.controller("SampleCtrl", function($scope, $firebaseArray, 

$firebaseAuth, $http) {
  var auth = $firebaseAuth();

  $scope.logIn = function login(){
    auth.$signInWithPopup("google").then(function(firebaseUser) {
      console.log("Signed in as:", firebaseUser.user.displayName);
    }).catch(function(error) {
      console.log("Authentication failed: ", error);
    });
  };

  auth.$onAuthStateChanged(function(firebaseUser){
    // firebaseUser will be null if not logged in
    if(firebaseUser) {
      // This is where we make our call to our server
      $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/secretData',
        headers: {
          id_token: firebaseUser._lat
        }
      }).then(function(response){
        $scope.secretData = response.data;
      });
    }else{
      console.log('Not logged in.');
      $scope.secretData = "Log in to get some secret data."
    }

  });

  $scope.logOut = function(){
    auth.$signOut().then(function(){
      console.log('Logging the user out!');
    });
  };
});
```

The full code can be found at [github](http://github.com/LukeSchlangen/nodeFire)

Comment: What versions are we working with? I presume this is AngularFire but it's not even mentioned here.

Comment: The latest versions pulled today. My repo is at GitHub.com/LukeSchlangen/nodeFire

Comment: Angular 1.5.8, Firebase 3.3.0, and AngularFire 2.0.2.

Comment: The `refreshToken` should be on the user object so you can access it like so: `firebaseAuth.user.refreshToken`. Checkout https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#signInWithPopup and https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User

Comment: Thanks idan. It looks like firebase recommends against that on the link you included? "A refresh token for the user account. Use only for advanced scenarios that require explicitly refreshing tokens."

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It is not clear what you are trying to do. Do not access obfuscated internal properties as these will change. You already noticed that. The correct way is to call getToken in the onAuthStateChanged listener:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    user.getIdToken().then(function(idToken) {
      console.log(idToken);
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: firebase.User.prototype.getToken is deprecated. Please use firebase.User.prototype.getIdToken instead.

Comment: Dat ".then"... works in my VueJS app! Thanx a lot :)